# Why the counter is incrementing n no of times in 1st post when there are n no of posts

Tags: jquery

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "main-comment">
            <textarea class = "textarea" rows = "5" cols = "35" placeholder = "Enter your comment ..."></textarea>
            <input type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "btn" value = "POST">
        </div>
        <div id = "comment_section">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var i = 0;
        var counter = 0;
        var current_selection = ' ';
        var template = '<div class = "comments" id = "%id%"><div class = "media"><div class = "media-body">             <p> %data% </p>         </div>          <div class = "media-footer" id="like_div">              <button class = "btn" id = "like">Like <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> </button><span class = "counter"> 0 </span>                        <a>Comment</a>          </div>      </div></div>';

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#btn").click(function(){
                i++;
                var l = template.replace('%data%', $(".textarea").val()).replace('%id%', 'comment' + i);
                $(".textarea").val(' ');
                $("#comment_section").append(l);
                $("#like_div .btn").click(function(){
                    current_selection = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
                    counter = parseInt($("#" + current_selection + " .counter").text());
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    $("#" + current_selection + " .counter").text(counter);
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem arises when there are more than 1 posts.
When there are 2 posts the 1st like button's counter is incremented by 2, likely when there are 3 posts the 1st like button's counter is incremented by 3.

Comment: NB: HTML with duplicate `id` attributes is invalid. You are generating such...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter increments more because you bind a click on `#like_div` which is *always* the first element with that ID. As your template has this ID, you'll produce many elements with the same ID, which is invalid HTML. The click handler will then always be bound to the first match. So you'll have the handler execute many times on the *first* `#like_div`.

You should not have `id` properties in your template HTML, and your inner click handler should be bound only to the *local* button. So search for it only *within* the new section that was added.

Here is how it could work:

```js
var i = 0;
var counter = 0;
var current_selection = ' ';
var template = `<div class="comments">
        <div class = "media">
            <div class = "media-body">
                <p> %data% <\/p>
            <\/div>
            <div class = "media-footer like_div">
                <button class = "btn like">Like <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"><\/span><\/button>
                <span class = "counter"> 0 <\/span>
                <a>Comment<\/a>
            <\/div>
        <\/div>
    <\/div>`;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var l = $(template.replace('%data%', $(".textarea").val())); // wrap in jQuery
        $("#comment_section").append(l);
        $(".textarea").val('');
        $(".like_div .btn", l).click(function(){ // only find the button within L
            var counterElem = $(this).closest(".comments").find(".counter");
            var counter = parseInt(counterElem.text());
            counterElem.text(counter + 1);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "main-comment">
        <textarea class = "textarea" rows = "5" cols = "35" placeholder = "Enter your comment ..."></textarea>
        <input type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" id="btn" value = "POST">
    </div>
    <div id = "comment_section">
    </div>
</div>
```

Note also, that you don't need to generate a dynamic id for each comment section. Just create the element by wrapping the template string in `$()`, and you'll have a reference to it. No need to use a search by a dynamic `id` attribute.